# Prove that $f_0$ is not an inner point of $A$ relative to $\lVert\cdot\rVert_1$

Tags: general-topology, analysis

Let $V=\big\{f:[0,1]\longrightarrow\mathbb{R}:f\text{ is continuous}\big\}$ and define the following norms:
$$\lVert f\rVert_1=\int_0^1|f(x)|dx$$
$$\lVert f\rVert_\infty=\max\big\{|f(x)|:x\in[0,1]\big\}$$
Now define $A=\big\{f\in V:\lVert f\rVert_\infty<1\big\}$ and $f_0(x)=0$, for all $x\in [0,1]$.

Prove that $f_0$ is **not** an inner point of $A$ relative to $\lVert\cdot\rVert_1$

I thought that the problem was in the functions that are below the $x$-axis whose integral is less than $1$, but the norm clearly does not allow negative values, any suggestions?

Comment: Hint: Consider $(n\epsilon/2)\chi_{(0,\frac 1 n)}$.

Comment: Those are not continuous but it is indeed the right idea (if you get rid of the first $n$). @geetha290krm

Answer (score 1, accepted):

**Hint**

Can you construct a sequence $f_n$ of continuous functions such that

- $f_n \notin A$ for all $n$
- $\|f_n-f_0\|_1 \to 0$ as $n \to \infty$

If such a sequence exists, why does it prove the statement ?

**Further help**

$f_0$ is not an inner point of $A$ if for every open set containing $f_0$, there is at least one element that is not in $A$. If a sequence $f_n$ that does not belong to $A$ but still converges to $f_0$, you have constructed such elements.

Indeed, assume $U$ is an open set containing $f_0$, then we can find a ball $B_{f_0,\varepsilon}$ centered at $f_0$ and of radius $\varepsilon$ such that $B_{f_0,\varepsilon} \subset U$. It is then enough to consider $f_n$ with $n$ large enough so $||f_n-f_0||_1<\varepsilon$.

Comment: Maybe that sequence is defined by $f_n=\frac{1}{nx}$ for all $x\in [0,1]$, clearly $\lVert f_n-f_0\rVert_1\rightarrow0$ as $n\rightarrow\infty$, then $f_n\notin A$ for all $n\in \mathbb{N}$ because it maximum point is greater than $1$, but that is what I don't understand, to show that $f_0$ is not a inner point of $A$, the point $f_n$ for $n\in \mathbb{N}$ which I am taking as reference must to be in $A$ and say that there is a neighbourhood that is not contained in $A$?

Comment: Sorry I did not see your edit at first. This sequence is not correct for two reasons : it is not continuous and $\|f_n\|_1$ does not exist for all $n$. I have edited my answer for further guidance.

Comment: Let the sequence $f_n=x^n$, for all $x\in [0,1]$. We have that $f_n\notin A$ because $\lVert f_n\rVert_\infty=1$ for all $n\in\mathbb{N}$, and note that $\lVert f_n-f_0\rVert_1\rightarrow 0$ as $n\rightarrow\infty$. This sequence show that $f_0$ is not a inner point of $A$ because for every $B(f_0,\varepsilon)$ such that $f_n\in B(f_0,\varepsilon)\not\subseteq$. Is this proof right or should I add or remove some detail?

Comment: I agree with this sequence. You could add further details but it mostly depends on who will read the proof.

Comment: You should write $B_{f_0,\varepsilon}\subset U$ in your answer instead of $B_{f_0,r}\subset U$.

Comment: Indeed, it is done. @Angelo

Comment: May I ask the reason for the downvote ? Did I say something wrong ?

Answer (score 1):

Let $\,\varepsilon\!\in\left]0,1\right[\,$ and consider the following function :

$f_\varepsilon(x)=\begin{cases}-\dfrac 1\varepsilon x+1\qquad\text{if }x\in\big[0,\varepsilon\big]\\0\qquad\qquad\quad\text{if }x\in\big]\varepsilon,1\big]\quad.\end{cases}$

The function $\,f_\varepsilon\,$ belongs to $\,V\,$ because it is continuous on $[0,1]\,,\,$ but it does not belong to $\,A\,$ since $\,\lVert f_\varepsilon\rVert_\infty=1\,.$

Moreover ,

$\displaystyle\lVert f_\varepsilon-f_0\rVert_1=\lVert f_\varepsilon\rVert_1=\int_0^1\left|f_\varepsilon(x)\right|\mathrm dx=\dfrac\varepsilon2<\varepsilon\,.$

Therefore, for any ball $\,B\left(f_0,\delta\right),\,$ where $\,\delta>0\,,\,$ there exists $\varepsilon=\min\left\{\delta,\dfrac12\right\}\in\big]0,1\big[\,$ such that $\,f_\varepsilon\in B\left(f_0,\delta\right)\setminus A\,.$

Consequently, there does not exist any ball $\,B\left(f_0,\delta\right)\subseteq A\,,$ hence $f_0$ is **not** an inner point of $A$ relative to $\lVert\cdot\rVert_1\,.$

Comment: Oh, I didn't see your answer, I'm taking a look at it...